# Why this pubnub game is going me too slow and how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

This is my code:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.27.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="464161591015-669suu0sat7n9c1lq2g6b3mn174g5sej.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px"class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script>
k=[]
obj={}
onkeydown=onkeyup=(e)=>{k[e.keyCode]=e.type=="keydown"}
onSignIn=(googleUser)=>{
 c=document.createElement("canvas")
 document.body.style.margin=0
 document.body.appendChild(c)
 ctx=c.getContext("2d")
 profile=googleUser.getBasicProfile()
 //console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()) // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
 //console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName())
 //console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl())
 //console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()) // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
 ID=profile.getId()
 username=profile.getName()
 imgURL=profile.getImageUrl()
 x=innerWidth/2
 y=innerHeight/2
 render=()=>{
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  c.width=innerWidth
  c.height=innerHeight
  //console.table(obj)
  pubnub.publish({
   channel:"hello_world",
   message:{ 
    content:ID,
    username:username,
    imgURL:imgURL,
    x:x,y:y
   }
  },(status, response)=>{
   console.log(status,response)
  })
  if(k[37]){x-=5}
  if(k[38]){y-=5}
  if(k[39]){x+=5}
  if(k[40]){y+=5}
  for(x2=Math.floor(x/32)*32-x;x2<innerWidth+64;x2+=32){
   for(y2=Math.floor(y/32)*32-y;y2<innerHeight+64;y2+=32){
    ctx.lineWidth=4
    ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(200,200,200,1)"
    ctx.strokeRect(x2,y2,32,32)
   }
  }
  for(i in obj){
   img=document.createElement("img")
   img.src=obj[i].imgURL
   ctx.drawImage(img,obj[i].x-x+innerWidth/2,obj[i].y-y+innerHeight/2,32,32)
   ctx.lineWidth=4
   ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)"
   ctx.strokeRect(obj[i].x-x+innerWidth/2,obj[i].y-y+innerHeight/2,32,32)
  }
 }
 connect=()=>{
  render()
 }
 pubnub = new PubNub({
  publishKey:'demo',
  subscribeKey:'demo',
  uuid:"myUniqueUUID"
 })
 pubnub.addListener({
  status:(statusEvent)=>{
   if(statusEvent.category==="PNConnectedCategory"){
    connect()
   }
  },
  message:(msg)=>{
   obj[msg.message.content]={username:msg.message.username,imgURL:msg.message.imgURL,x:msg.message.x,y:msg.message.y}
  },
  presence:(presenceEvent)=>{}
 })

 pubnub.subscribe({
  channels:['hello_world'] 
 })
}
</script>
```

Explanation:

I want a .io game like agar.io, so this is only a start. I tried to do a game like agar.io with the google verification API, adding the X and Y new properties to the user, and I finally created this game, but... it renders too slow. Only 1 frame per 300ms. The ping is high. How can I solve it?

Comment: Is this using websockets or HTTP?

Comment: HTTP, I suspect, because I rode the WebSocket protocol isn't supported yet...

Comment: Are you actually using the "demo" PubNub keys? If so, those or throttled because they are for simple public demo apps on our site. If you haven't yet created your own PubNub account, do so and use your own key set. But create a new key set and do not use the ones that are created for you because that first set is also throttled. go to https://admin.pubnub.com to create your account. Let us all know if that helped. If it doesn't submit your key set and issue to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and they can assist you further.

Comment: The first thing I would try is move the `requestAnimationFrame(render)` statement to the _end_ of render. I would also confirm that `connect` is not being called repeatedly.

Comment: Also, use `signal` instead of `publish`. I'm pretty sure that is what you want to use for this use case. See docs [signal API ref](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe#signal) and [signal listener callback](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-publish-and-subscribe#listeners).

Comment: It is http long polling. There may be some design patterns and best practices you need to  follow for high publish rate. Using signals is one thing to think about. PubNub Support can get the right resources for you, too.

Comment: Another thing you can try is use Chrome DevTools to double check that the rate of inbound messages is not unreasonably high. Look for the long-polling HTTP request.

Comment: I now added my own pubnub key, but I'm studying how to replace the publish by the signal function. Thanks.

Comment: replace `publish` with `signal` and copy/past `message` callback and change `message` to `signal`. That should do it. Just be sure the message payload is < 30 bytes. I didn't check that part of your app.

Comment: I added a publish with the profile picture, the username and the position, and I added a constant signal with only the position, and it gives me this error, sorry >< :
`{message: "Missing Message", type: "validationError", error: true}`
I'm trying that at http://drwerenverlivitz.atspace.cc/ ... should I edit my question?

Comment: let me see your full signal code. maybe update your original question post above?

Comment: nm, i just looked at source at the link you provided. In your `signal` code, `signal` should be `message`. In your `addListener` you need to make a `signal` callback just like `message` callback. I think my advise might have been confusing. `pubnub.signal({
    message: {'msg':'hello'},
    channel: 'foo'
});`

Comment: `{error: true, operation: "PNPublishOperation", statusCode: 400, errorData: Array(3), category: "PNBadRequestCategory"}` ><'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209933/discussion-between-drwerenverlivitz-and-craig-conover).